# Upsert always updates postgresql even not matching where clause

Tags: postgresql, pg

I have sql query:

```
INSERT INTO books VALUES (12, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
ON CONFLICT (id) 
WHERE version IS NULL OR updated + INTERVAL '2min' < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
DO UPDATE SET version = books.version + 1, updated = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

however even if the where clause is not true, the row is updated. Here's example: https://dbfiddle.uk/CPHvZDm3

I can't understand what is wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

The location of the `WHERE` clause is the issue. Corrected statement below.

```
CREATE TABLE books (
    id int4 NOT NULL,
    version int8 NOT NULL,
    updated timestamp NULL,
    CONSTRAINT books_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO books VALUES (12, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
ON CONFLICT (id) 
DO UPDATE 
SET version = books.version + 1, updated = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE books.version IS NULL OR books.updated + INTERVAL '2min' < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

select *, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, updated + INTERVAL '2min' < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP from books where id = 12;

 id | version |          updated           |       current_timestamp        | ?column? 
----+---------+----------------------------+--------------------------------+----------
 12 |       0 | 11/13/2022 10:34:06.028222 | 11/13/2022 10:34:06.055526 PST | f


INSERT INTO books VALUES (12, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
ON CONFLICT (id) 
DO UPDATE 
SET version = books.version + 1, updated = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE books.version IS NULL OR books.updated + INTERVAL '2min' < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

select *, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, updated + INTERVAL '2min' < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP from books where id = 12

 id | version |          updated           |       current_timestamp        | ?column? 
----+---------+----------------------------+--------------------------------+----------
 12 |       0 | 11/13/2022 10:34:06.028222 | 11/13/2022 10:34:08.668121 PST | f
```

From docs [INSERT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html):

```
and conflict_action is one of:

    DO NOTHING
     DO UPDATE SET { column_name = { expression | DEFAULT } |
                    ( column_name [, ...] ) = [ ROW ] ( { expression |  DEFAULT } [, ...] ) |
                    ( column_name [, ...] ) = ( sub-SELECT )
                  } [, ...]
              [ WHERE condition ]
```